# NDB Validator Prop Fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, error-handling, validation

I rolled a custom validator for my ndb stringProperties to strip out malicious code for my website.

```
def stringValidator(prop, value):
  lowerValue = value.lower()
  stripped = str(utils.escape(lowerValue))

  if stripped != lowerValue:
    raise datastore_errors.BadValueError(prop)

  return stripped
```

Elsewhere, I'm catching that error and returning a failure to the client. I want to be able to return the type of the property that failed validation.

```
except datastore_errors.BadValueError as err:
```

If I `print(err)` I get:

```
StringProperty('email', validator=<function stringValidator at 0x1079e11b8>)
```

I see that this StringProperty contains the name of the property I want to return:  `'email'`. How do I extract it?

EDIT: Dmitry gave me the most important half the answer - in order to access the error object's value once I pass the ._name property, I need to use:

```
str(err.args[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get name of the property by `_name` attribute.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

def stringValidator(prop, value):
  lowerValue = value.lower()
  stripped = 'bla'

  if stripped != lowerValue:
    raise datastore_errors.BadValueError(prop._name)

  return stripped

class Foo(ndb.Model):
  email = ndb.StringProperty(validator=stringValidator)

Foo(email='blas')  # raises BadValueError: email
```

**Update**: you can also use "human friendly" property name by setting

```
email = ndb.StringProperty(validator=stringValidator, verbose_name='E-mail')
```

in the property definition, and then get it by `_verbose_name` attribute.